# how does nonlocal function store values in Python

Tags: python

I'm confused about how the get() function works. How can it read the previous values? Are the values are stored in f function? How?

```
def nonlocalist():
    get = lambda x:'Index out of range!'
    def prepend(value):
        nonlocal get
        f = get
        def get(i):
            if i == 0:
                return value
            return f(i - 1)
    return prepend, lambda x: get(x)

prepend, get = nonlocalist()
prepend(2)
prepend(3)
prepend(4)

get(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are stored in function objects.  Each call to `prepend` creates a new `get` function object that refers to the preceding `get` function object, which still exists, and each `get` function object that `prepend` creates stores the `value` parameter passed to `prepend`.

When `nonlocalist` is called, `get` refers to the lambda function that returns the 'Index out of range!' message.  Let's call this `get0`.  (This term is defined just for this discussion.  It doesn't mean anything in the code itself.)

Then when `prepend` is called after that, it sets `f` to refer to `get0`.  Then it redefines `get` and the new `get` function object has the `value` passed to `prepend` bound into it.  We'll call this new `get` function `get1`.  Now if `get1` is called with a parameter of zero, it will return the value passed to `prepend`.  If it gets called with any other parameter, it will call `f`, which refers to `get0`, with a parameter of zero, and that function, as we have seen, will return the error message regardless of its parameter.

At this point, the `get1` function is around because it was just defined and the `get0` function is also still around because `get1` holds a reference to it as `f`.

The next call to `prepend` generates a new function object `get2`, which stores that `prepend` call's `value` and calls `get1` (as `f`).  When it calls `f`, it subtracts 1 from the subscript argument `i`, so `i` controls how far the `f` calls travel down the list.

So each call to `prepend` generates a new and different `get`*n* function object that contains a `value` from `prepend` and a reference to the preceding `get`*(n - 1)* function, all the way back to `get0`.

In conclusion, I must say:  that is one gnarly nest of functions.